# Quantum Non-Demolition of entangled superposition using an electron with infinite spin

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-information, quantum-spin, soft-question, quantum-entanglement

**Disclaimer: I have no idea what I am talking about, as I just started college and barely understand quantum physics.**

If an electron can have a linear velocity of the speed of light, theoretically electrons could be created that have an angular velocity of the speed of light they would produce an area of infinitely thin [frame dragging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frame-dragging). Any particle that interacts with these theoretical particles would experience 'weird effects'.

Could these effects possibly allow the reading (or detecting) of a superposition, violating the observer effect/uncertainty principle?

I assume that if a superposition could be read in its entirety or detected without collapsing the particle into an eigen-state, this could be used to send information FTL as by reading the particles probability wave, you can determine if it has been observed (collapsed) without doing so yourself.

If I have got anything wrong, please don't hesitate to correct me.

Comment: Particles with mass that are colloquially said to move "at" the speed of light don't actually do so - they travel at finite speed and therefore at finite momentum. Particles that travel at exactly the speed of light must have zero mass, though they still have finite momentum. (For the details of how that works, see [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/2229/if-photons-have-no-mass-how-can-they-have-momentum).) Infinite linear momentum is not a thing. With that in mind, maybe there's parts of this question that you might want to rephrase.

Comment: I'll get on that.

Comment: For what it's worth, a lot of things in physics are like math in the sense that if one nonsense thing is true, then any other nonsense thing is true. For example, if you use $0=1$ as a postulate, you can prove pretty much whatever nonsense you want. My guess would be that if we allow for massive particles moving at the speed of light, any and all nonsense will follow. It can be instructive to see how those proofs work though, and a good answer to this question could go that route.

Comment: What they said. Although nothing with mass can travel exactly at *c* there's no theoretical limit to how high its linear momentum can be; charged particles in circular motion tend to lose energy by radiation. You may enjoy [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/234619/123208) about relativistic electrons in atoms.

Comment: @DanielSank This is true of almost any system of formal logic (which includes physics, math, computer science, and some philosophy, among other disciplines), and it's referred to as the awesomely-titled Principle of Explosion. See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_explosion